# Hashes and Smart Match Operators in Perl

Tags: perl, match, operator-keyword, hash

For a programme that I must write for an assignment. I've been told to use either a Smart Match Operator or Hashes. My problem is, is that I just don't understand how they work or what they do no matter what I read in textbooks or on the internet. I don't suppose somebody could explain their function to me really simply?

The final part of the assignment is to deduce the number of unique species in an area - I've calculated which species are the in the area but I don't know how to calculate the total number of species.

For example if in a tiny area there are 4 birds:

```
2 Red Kite
1 Robin 
1 Duck
```

I know there are 4 birds in total but I don't know how to work out that there are 3 species in that particular area.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://perlmaven.com/perl-hashes).

Comment: As of Perl 5.18, [smart match is experimental](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5180delta.html#The-smartmatch-family-of-features-are-now-experimental): *"It is clear that smartmatch is almost certainly either going to change or go away in the future. Relying on its current behavior is not recommended."*

Comment: Smart match should never have gone directly into core. There's some cleaner reimplementantions on CPAN. Two that come to mind are Smart::Match (https://metacpan.org/pod/Smart::Match) and match::simple (https://metacpan.org/pod/match::simple)

Comment: Smart::Matches still requires the use of smart-matching, but in a way that's likely to continue working.

Comment: @Arkturaz: You should tell your instructor that he shouldn't be teaching smart matching.

Comment: Thank you :) the assignment isn't due until the 21st but I want to finish it so I can focus on my dissertation. 
I should have expanded more - I have to sort 125,000 animals and If I do it by hashes then I have to put each one in by the looks of things (Though I might not be understanding it correctly) - The subroutine I'm writing for it shouldn't be longer than 20-25 lines of code and I have around 16 so far so I don't know if I'm over complicating it in my head :/

Comment: @Arkturaz: Quite likely you are over-complicating things. I don't understand what you mean by *"put each one in"*.

Comment: Sorry - I was assuming that I would need to put each animal into its own hash so it could be counted but I completely misunderstood it.

Comment: @Arkturaz: No. Each animal has a single *element* of a hash that contains the information about all animals. In this case the *value* of that element is the count of sightings, but it could be anything. You may be able to talk to me in [this chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/49087/perl-hashes) but I think your experience of 13 is too low.

Comment: Yeah I need to be rank 20; never mind. I've been playing around with your reply below and I got an error message of "Reference found where even-sized list expected" - Which funnily enough tells me I'm moving forward at least haha

Answer (score 1):

Well, smart match is experimental and likely to be changed, so I wouldn't use it. (*It is clear that smartmatch is almost certainly either going to change or go away in the future. Relying on its current behavior is not recommended.*)

A hash is an implementation of a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), a data structure designed for quick lookup of elements keyed by a string. Think of it as an array with strings for indexes rather than integers.

Another feature of hashes is that you can can enumerate the keys of the elements within (using `keys` in list context) and you can count them (using `keys` in scalar context). This can be useful for grouping items. Consider what elements exist after you execute the following:

```
$birds{"Red Kite"} = 1;
$birds{"Red Kite"} = 1;
$birds{"Robin"}    = 1;
$birds{"Duck"}     = 1;
```

You end up with three elements whose keys are `Red Kite`, `Robin` and `Duck`. Just use a loop instead of hardcoding the values to populate the hash, then use `keys` to count the number of resulting elements, and you got your answer.

---

Bonus: I just used an arbitrary value in the above, since it was sufficient to achieve your goal. But consider what you would get if you incremented the value of the element instead of setting it.

```
++$birds{"Red Kite"};
++$birds{"Red Kite"};
++$birds{"Robin"};
++$birds{"Duck"};
```

You end up with the number of birds of each species!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a hash, which is a data structure that you can access using a *string*.

You can compare hashes to arrays.

Each element of an array has an *index* and a *value*, so the value of the element of `@data` for index `2` is `$data[2]`. Similarly, each element of a hash has a *key* and a *value*, so the value of the element of `%bird_count` for key `Red Kite` is `$bird_count{'Red Kite'}`. (Notice the use of braces instead of brackets to access hash elements.)

Where an array like `@data` can be accessed using integers, so the third element is `$data[2]`, a hash like `%bird_counts` can be accessed using a string, so the count for Red Kites is `$bird_count{'Red Kite'}`.

If you had a program that counted birds as they were observed, it could do

```
++$bird_count{'Red Kite'};

++$bird_count{'Robin'};

++$bird_count{'Red Kite'};

++$bird_count{'Duck'};
```

after which the hash would have *three* elements: `$bird_count{'Red Kite'}` would be `2` and the other two would be `1`. Try it.

You can count the number of different birds by counting the number of *keys* of the hash, so

```
my $num_different_birds = keys %bird_count;
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks you Borodin, I'll give this ago :)