# Perl array element comparing

Tags: arrays, perl

I am new in Perl programming. I am trying to compare the two arrays each element. So here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10.1;

my @x = ("tom","john","michell");
my @y = ("tom","john","michell","robert","ricky");
if (@x ~~ @y)
{
    say "elements matched"; 
}
else 
{ 
    say "no elements matched";
}
```

When I run this I get the output 
`no elements matched`

So I want to compare both array elements in deep and the element do not matches, those elements I want to store it in a new array. As I can now compare the only matched elements but I can't store it in a new array.

How can I store those unmatched elements in a new array?

Please someone can help me and advice.

Comment: `@array1 ~~ @array2` checks if the each index matches the same index in the other array. As `perlop` documentations says, it's like `($array1[0] ~~ $array2[0]) && ($array1[1] ~~ $array2[1]) && ... ` etc. Ultimately, your else statement is wrong, and should really say "some or all elements do not match". The only way to do what you want is to create a lookup table (hash) or iterate one array over the other... Both of which have already been provided as answers.

Comment: Array::Compare is ideal for your problem. http://search.cpan.org/~davecross/Array-Compare-2.11/lib/Array/Compare.pm#DESCRIPTION   It is capable of listing out non-matched elements.

Comment: To clarify your question... are you wanting to compare the same index across both arrays? That is... does it matter if `tom` is in `$x[0]` but in `$y[1]` ... OR ... must `tom` be in `$x[0]` and `$y[0]` ?

Comment: no i am not comparing both index..

Comment: You should avoid using smart matching. It is an experimental feature that is a bit broken and is highly likely to change in future versions of Perl

Answer (score 5):

I'd avoid smart matching in Perl - e.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22206061/hashes-and-smart-match-operators-in-perl)

If you're trying to compare the contents of `$y[0]` with `$x[0]` then this is one way to go, which puts all non-matches in an new array `@keep`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;

my @x = qw(tom john michell);
my @y = qw(tom john michell robert ricky);

my @keep;
for (my $i = 0; $i <$#y; $i++) {
    unless ($y[$i] eq $x[$i]){
        push @keep, $y[$i];
    }
}

say for @keep;
```

---

Or, if you simply want to see if one name ***exists*** in the other array (and aren't interested in directly comparing elements), use two hashes:

```
my (%x, %y);

$x{$_}++ for @x;
$y{$_}++ for @y;

foreach (keys %y){
    say if not exists $x{$_};
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment for my answer. I not clearly read the question. Then i tried negative smart match is not work.

Comment: In the first way i can get only one element..whereas i suppose to get 2 elements?

Comment: That's because there are an unequal number of elements in the two arrays.

Answer (score 1):

It would be well worth your while spending some time reading the [Perl FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq.html).

[Perl FAQ 4](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq.html) concerns Data Manipulation and includes the following question and answer:

> **How do I compute the difference of two arrays? How do I compute 
>   the intersection of two arrays?**
>
> Use a hash. Here's code to do both and more. It assumes that each
>   element is unique in a given array:
>
> ```
> my (@union, @intersection, @difference);
> my %count = ();
> foreach my $element (@array1, @array2) { $count{$element}++ }
> foreach my $element (keys %count) {
>     push @union, $element;
>     push @{ $count{$element} > 1 ? \@intersection : \@difference }, $element;
> }
> ```
>
> Note that this is the symmetric difference, that is, all elements 
>   in either A or in B but not in both. Think of it as an xor
>   operation.